Plotting a timeseries as bar plot with pandas results in an incorrect year
I have the following dataframe (except my actual data is over 25 years):
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        date=pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-12-31", freq="MS"),
        data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    ), 
)
df

Output:
    date    data
0   2020-01-01  1
1   2020-02-01  2
2   2020-03-01  3
3   2020-04-01  4
4   2020-05-01  5
5   2020-06-01  6
6   2020-07-01  7
7   2020-08-01  8
8   2020-09-01  9
9   2020-10-01  10
10  2020-11-01  11
11  2020-12-01  12

And I get different results with matplotlib and pandas default plotting:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = mpl.figure.Figure(constrained_layout=True)
axs = fig.subplot_mosaic("ac;bd")

ax = axs["a"]
ax.bar(x="date", height="data", data=df, width=15)

ax = axs["b"]
ax.bar(x="date", height="data", data=df, width=15)

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=12, maxticks=24)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

ax = axs["c"]
df.plot.bar(x="date", y="data", ax=ax, legend=False)

ax = axs["d"]

df.plot.bar(x="date", y="data", ax=ax, legend=False, ) # incorrect year -> 1970 instead of 2020

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=12, maxticks=24)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

for k, ax in axs.items():
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(40)
        label.set_horizontalalignment('right')

fig

Output:

I would like to be able to use pandas for plotting but then format the ticks appropriately for a publication ready plot. However, it appears that I lose the date time information or get the incorrect year when using pandas.
Is there a way to format the axis ticklabels using mdates features without using the data directly? i.e. if I resample the data, or slice in a different year, I'd like the axis to reflect that automatically.

Here's a more simple illustration of the issue I'm having:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = mpl.figure.Figure(constrained_layout=True)
axs = fig.subplot_mosaic("a")

ax = axs["a"]

df.plot.bar(x="date", y="data", ax=ax, legend=False) # incorrect year -> 1970 instead of 2020

formatter = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y - %b")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

fig


The dates are all wrong when using DateFormatter.

What axis labels do you want? All the examples look correct to me. All data points are in the same year (2020) and you used a ConciseDateFormatter so the year only shows up for the first data point. Use a DateFormatter if you want a specific format for all labels.

I want to use the code for the last plot (bottom right) but the year for that shows up as 1970-Jan.

pandas documentation says it calls fig.autoformat_xdate() but when I call that manually I don't get the same results in matplotlib. Is this a bug in pandas? How do I get pandas to behave the same way as matplotlib should?

btw, even using DateFormatter doesn't work. It seems like after plotting with pandas, the matplotlib built-in mdates features don't work as expected.

When you are using a bar plot, the x-coordinates become 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. That's why mdates.DateFormatter returns 1970, as it treats these coordinates as seconds since epoch time.
You can set the tick labels manually:
ax.set_xticklabels(df["date"].dt.strftime("%Y - %b"))


Thanks for your answer, that appears to be the issue.
Specifically, unfortunately, it looks like when one uses df.plot(kind="bar"), pandas always treats the x axis as categorical values. I switched to using area plots instead of bar plots.

I've opened an issue on pandas-dev/pandas for a suggestion to improve bar plots with datetime indices: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/59543
